# ¿Como enviar el valor de un input a php dentro del mismo HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el valor en un input que pretendo heredar el valor a una variable en php, con esta variable invocar a una función. Pego el Código:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container col-sm-12">
                        <form action="cargarArchivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <input type="file" name="file" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <button class="form-control" type="submit" id="btnAdjuntar">Adjuntar Archivo</button>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="txtBox" name="idAdjArchivo" id="idAdjArchivo" style="display: none;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <?php 
                            $ID_EMISION = 7;
                            echo fnDTADJUNTOS($ID_EMISION); 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

El valor que contiene este input (valor obtenido por javascript):

```
<input class="form-control" type="txtBox" name="idAdjArchivo" id="idAdjArchivo" style="display: none;">
```

Lo ocupo en:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <?php 
                    $ID_EMISION = 7;
                    echo fnDTADJUNTOS($ID_EMISION); 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Ya que en es ese container devuelvo un DataTable Dinamico donde ocupo el valor del input. Esta estátido por eso le asigne a $ID_EMISION un valor.

Alguien tiene una idea? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre es que metas ese `input` en un `form` y utilices la función de JS `submit()` para enviar el contenido al servidor web y recibirlo en la variable superglobal `$_POST` en PHP.

Algo así:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="formulario">
    <input class="form-control" type="txtBox"
        name="idAdjArchivo" id="idAdjArchivo"
        style="display:none;"/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var f=document.getElementById('formulario');
f.submit();
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['idAdjArchivo']))
        echo fnDTADJUNTOS($_POST['idAdjArchivo']); 
?>
```

Para que no ejecute el PHP de forma inmediata: En la parte de JS, ponle alguna condición antes del `submit()`. Por ejemplo, que haya cambiado el contenido del `input` o que el usuario haya pulsado algo. Si no, efectivamente, hace el envío nada más cargar la página.

Si necesitas ayuda con esta parte, coméntamelo y continúo ampliando.

Comment: Gracias, lo coloque como lo sugieres pero me marca error en la parte de PHP ya que me indica que 'idAdjArchivo' no está definido: Notice: Undefined index: idAdjArchivo

Comment: Ese error aparece porque, al iniciar la web, aún no se ha recibido ningún `$_POST`. Acabo de editar la respuesta, prueba así

Comment: Gracias me ha sido de mucha utilidad. Funciona de maravilla solo que tiene un pero que debo dar solución. Al cargar la página ya tiene un valor 'idAdjArchivo' cuando vuelvo a invocar la función no hace el cambio sino hasta que refresco la página. Debo encontrar la manera de recargar la página para que el valor pase de forma dinámica.

Comment: Ok, te dejo la respuesta ampliada